# Accessing the history of a `ref` in Clojure

Tags: clojure, stm

The [documentation for ref](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/ref) shows a :max-history option and states that "refs accumulate history dynamically as needed to deal with read demands."  I can see that there is history at the REPL, but I don't see how to find previous values of a ref:

```
user=> (def the-world (ref "hello" :min-history 10))
#'user/the-world
user=> (do
          (dosync (ref-set the-world "better"))
          @the-world)
"better"
user=> (let [exclamator (fn [x] (str x "!"))]
          (dosync
           (alter the-world exclamator)
           (alter the-world exclamator)
           (alter the-world exclamator))
          @the-world)
"better!!!"
user=> (ref-history-count the-world)
2
```

Presumably the-world has had the values "hello", "better", and "better!!!".  How do I access that history?

If it is not possible to access that history, is there a datatype that keeps a history of its values that can be queried afterwards?  Or is that why the datomic database was created?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe :min-history and :max-history only refer the history of a ref during a transaction.

However, here's a way to do it with an atom and a watcher:

```
user> (def the-world (ref "hello"))
#'user/the-world
user> (def history-of-the-world (atom [@the-world]))
#'user/history-of-the-world
user> history-of-the-world
#<Atom@6ef167bb: ["hello"]>
user> (add-watch the-world :historian
                 (fn [key world-ref old-state new-state]
                   (if (not= old-state new-state)
                     (swap! history-of-the-world conj new-state))))
#<Ref@47a2101a: "hello">
user> (do
        (dosync (ref-set the-world "better"))
        @the-world)
"better"      
user> (let [exclamator (fn [x] (str x  "!"))]
        (dosync
          (alter the-world exclamator)
          (alter the-world exclamator)
          (alter the-world exclamator))
        @the-world)
"better!!!"
user> @history-of-the-world
["hello" "better" "better!!!"]
```

Comment: Will this work the same with atoms too?